# Morphia: Migrating existing data from Morphia 1.x to 2.x

Tags: java, mongodb, migration, morphia

I am trying to update the Morphia version from 1.x to 2.x.
While doing that i have noticed that now the discriminator in the database is also changed.
previously it was `className="app.package.className"` and now it is changed to `_t="className"`.
I found that we can explicitly mention the `discriminatorKey` and `discriminator` in the `@Entity` annotation as a parameter.
But still I am not very sure how can i migrate existing data to support the new discriminator in version 2.x.

```
@Entity(discriminatorKey="className", discriminator="Unit")
public class Unit {
    @Id
    private String id;
    protected Unit() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I had encountered a same situation. You can create two different `Datastore` of the new morphia package. The first one with legacy `MapperOptions` and the second with the new default `MapperOptions`.

```java
Datastore datastoreLegacy = Morphia.createDatastore("dbName", MapperOptions.legacy().build());
Datastore datastoreNew = Morphia.createDatastore("dbName");
```

Then you can use the legacy datastore to query documents from your `Unit` collection and store them with the new datastore. This example shows how to perform it on every document in two statements. If the collection has a lot of data, then you should probably iterate over all documents.

```java
List<Unit> units = datastoreLegacy.find(Unit.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
datastoreNew.save(units);
```